# Replacing only the first match of a global regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm writing a function to recursively replace matches of a regex in a string. The replacement can be a function, as with vanilla `.replace`, and this function can access the original string through one of its arguments.

I would like my function to replace only one match on each iteration. With a non-global regex, this will always be the case. However, some of the regexes this function receives will be global. Doing a traditional `.replace(regex, replacement)` means it could replace multiple times on each iteration, not only messing up the order in which the matches are processed, but also passing an incorrect index and original string to the replacement function.

As an example:

```
function recursiveReplace(string, regex, replacement) {
  for (var i = 1e8; i > 0 && regex.test(string); i--)
    string = string.replace(regex, replacement);
  return string;
}

console.log(
  recursiveReplace("abcdef", /../g, function (match, index, original) {
    console.log(original);
    return match[0];
  })
);
```

This outputs

```
abcdef
abcdef
abcdef
ace
ae
a
```

when the desired output is

```
abcdef
acdef
adef
aef
af
a
```

How can I get the function to process only one match on each iteration, whether the regex has the `g` flag or not? Note that I'm using the function in such a way that the second argument will always be a regex (I have no control over this, nor over whether or not said regex has the `g` flag).

Comment: Isn't `1e8` always 1 ?

Comment: Running a `ReExp#test` with a `g` based regex can cause issues, too. It is much better to pass a string pattern to the method, and compile appropriate RegExp objects with the relevant modifiers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Interesting, I'd never heard of that. The problem with your suggestion is that I'm using the function in a place where the second input will always be a regex (I have no control over that).

Comment: Since `replacement` is a string replacement pattern, your best bet is to parse out the pattern and flags from the regex object,  recreate without `g` .

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It would seem I can do this with just `regex = RegExp(regex, regex.flags.replace('g', ''));`. Problem solved, I guess, but I'm not sure how cross-platform this is.

Comment: @sln `xey` or `xEy` means `x * 10**y` (with `**` being exponentiation)

Comment: @NickA  - sorry, I've been out of engineering for a while now. I thought it was x ** y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that the best way to do this would be to just manually remove the `g` flag from the regex. Here's the most cross-platform way I could find to do this, using `regex.toString()` to get the string representation of the regex:

```
function recursiveReplace(string, regex, replacement) {
  regex = eval(regex.toString().replace(/[a-z]*$/, function (s) {
    return s.replace('g', '');
  }));
  for (var i = 1e8; i > 0 && regex.test(string); i--)
    string = string.replace(regex, replacement);
  return string;
}
```

With the ES6 features [`RegExp(regex)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description) and [`RegExp#flags`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/flags) this gets much easier:

```js
function recursiveReplace(string, regex, replacement) {
  regex = RegExp(regex, regex.flags.replace('g', ''));
  for (var i = 1e8; i > 0 && regex.test(string); i--)
    string = string.replace(regex, replacement);
  return string;
}
```

Comment: `.flags` is not ES6 (though many supported before) but you can use the standardized regex.toString() and extract the flags manually

Comment: Yes, true, and also `flags` property is not supported in IE, Opera and Safari. [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/toString) is supported.

Comment: I've added an approach that uses no ES6 features. Thanks for the help, guys.

Comment: Forgive me if I misunderstand, but won't that match any occurrence of `g`, stripping them from the original regex as well? For example, if we had `[a-g]` instead of `[a-z]`, wouldn't that be a problem? The five possible expression flags following the last `/` are `gimuy`, so I think we need a regex to match only that last `g` inside of `return s.replace();` Somebody please share if you know what such syntax would look like.